# "Household chores" is a common phrase, what about housework chores? Is it also used anywhere?

Tags: vocabulary

I know the phrase "household chores" is much more common. Tell me if the phrase "housework chores" is also used anywhere in the English speaking world, most probably in Australia or New Zealand or somewhere else?

Comment: *Housework chores* seems redundant— either *housework* or *chores* would convey the idea, at least in non-agricultural settings were there are no farm chores to do.

Comment: No "homework chores", unlike the idiomatic "household chores", is not used. Housework and chores are synonyms. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=household+chores%2Chomework+chores&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chousehold%20chores%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chomework%20chores%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I can't say that I've ever heard the term "housework chores" used anywhere in the US, except possibly in the Department of Redundancy Department.

Answer (score 4):

*Household* and *housework* are very different concepts.
*Household* means a residence , associated property and those that live there [Oxford Dictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/household).
*Housework* would be the work to maintain a house in order, particularly cleaning. [Oxford Dictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/housework)

*Housework* is in itself *household* work, adding chores to *housework* would be redundant. That would not be good English, and is not accepted usage.
One may have *household chores*, or *housework*, but not *housework chores.*

Answer (score 2):

Apart from **household chores**, there is another alternative:

**domestic chores**, the adjective *domestic* is not redundant and as an expression it is perfectly idiomatic. The term *domestic* refers to the running of the household (home).

It is the perfect synonym for the compound noun, **housework**,  which already contains the meaning of *chore*, in *work*. A mundane, repetitive, but necessary  job is called a *chore*, and [*household work*](http://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/household-work-strategy) is precisely that.

> **2** [only before noun] relating to family relationships and life at home
>
> - *Unfortunately his **domestic life** wasn’t very happy*.
>
> domestic tasks/chores/responsibilities etc
>
> - *Nowadays there is more sharing of **domestic chores***.
> - families that can afford **domestic help** (=help with cleaning, washing etc)
> - an organization that supports women facing **domestic violence** (=violence in a family, especially from a husband to his wife)

Source *[Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/domestic)*